# RID lookup - logical search

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan, b-tree

For example we have table with clustered index table1 (col1 int , col2 int , col3 int), clustered index defined for col1, non-clustered index defined for col2, we write query - select * from  table1 where col2 = 'some value' - optimizer comes to non-clustered index seek, grabs specific row and goes to clustered index to grab rest of data that not contained inside of non-clustered index (performs key lookup to grab col3 in this case). Key lookup essentially is clustered index seek based on clustered index value that was found in non-clustered index on leaf level.

What happens when we don't have clustered index on table but we have non-clustered index? I know that it will perform RID lookup but how this logically works? Clustered index value will be found using b-tree search as we have all rows in particular order but how this will be found in heap table without any particular order? Per my understanding when we found row inside non-clustered index (this has non-clustered index key + rowid) we need to scan whole heap table to find this rowid there because we do not have any order there and can not navigate this row using b-tree , is it correct?

Comment: The rowid usually includes information of the logical disk segment to read in the tablespace. That means only a single I/O operation is needed to retrieve the row from the heap. Moreover, because of low level caching, the I/O segment may be already in memory, so most of the time it's pretty much instantaneous. This is why high end databases (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) use the heap model instead of clustered index model (that is slower).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example may help. Below creates a heap and inserts a couple of rows to it

```
CREATE TABLE Demo(X CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO Demo VALUES ('A'), ('B');
```

You can then use the following to see the RID

```
SELECT X,
       %%physloc%% as rid, 
       sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) as formatted
FROM Demo
```

Which for me returns

```
+---+--------------------+-----------+
| X |        rid         | formatted |
+---+--------------------+-----------+
| A | 0xE700000001000000 | (1:231:0) |
| B | 0xE700000001000100 | (1:231:1) |
+---+--------------------+-----------+
```

The RID is an 8 byte binary value which is a concatenation of three components. `FileNumber:PageNumber:SlotNumber`.

Each file is divided up into 8KB pages with numbering starting at 0 so it is straightforward to calculate the offset in the file for a given page number. Page 231 is the 8KB section starting at byte offset 1892352 in the file (`231 * 8192`).

To locate the row belonging to RID `1:231:1` it just needs to get that relevant page (`1:231`) from the buffer manager (which will read it from disc if needed) and go to the second slot on the page (the slot numbering starts from 0).

Each data page has a [slot array](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) in the footer giving the offset of the row for every row on the page.

Answer (score 4):

This is a conceptual explanation.  The database stores rows on data pages, which in turn store rows.  The `rid` directly identifies the location of the row in terms of the "physical" location.  Actually, the data page is "logical" in the sense that it could be in memory or on disk.

The database does not need to go through the user-facing indexes to identify where the row is.  It needs to identify the page and then the offset on the page.  The `rid` has information about which page and the offset.  So, the page management system can directly find the page that it needs from the rid.

There is no need to scan anything to find the row.

That said, there are things that the database has to do, such as:

- Is the data page in the page cache?  If not, then go get it.
- Has the page in memory been modified?  If not, are dirty reads allowed.
- Is the row locked?

Management of the storage layer is often overlooked in understanding how databases function.  In terms of writing queries day-to-day, the page management just seems to work.  However, accessing a row is not really a simple operation.  Much of the powerful functionality of databases in terms of ACID properties, reliability, and scalability rest on the storage management layer.

Comment: Thank for you reply , but I still do not understand how RDBMS can fast understand which page need to be read ? For example we already has this specific page inside bufferpool , how SQL server can fast search this page ?